# Failed to deploy Azure Function App with Python script containing azure.storage.fileshare

Tags: python, azure

I am new to Python and Azure Function App. I was able to deploy the default http_trigger function using the Visual Studio Code with Azure Function App without issue. However, when I tried to add a simple from azure.storage.fileshare, it just doesn't create the function http_trigger file.

Azure Function App with http_trigger function created

Comment: can you share the code which you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an http trigger function with a Python runtime environment in VS Code.

-The `azure.storage.fileshare` package has been installed.

**Function code:**

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareClient
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    storage_account_name = 'storepavan3'
    file_share_name = 'fileshare23'
    file_path = 'pavan.txt'
    connection_string ="your-connection-string"
    share_client = ShareClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, share_name=file_share_name)
    file_client = share_client.get_file_client(file_path)
    file_contents = file_client.download_file().readall()
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {file_contents}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
        )
```

**Requirement.txt:**

```
azure-functions
azure-storage-file-share
```

By using the above code, I am able to retrieve the data about the file present in the file share.
The above code executed successfully in my local environment. Check below:

[image]

The above code was successfully deployed into the Azure portal.
**deployment status:**

[image]

The Http function runs successfully in the Azure Portal.
Check below:

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me debug further and I found there were 2 issues:
1. requirements.txt - needs to include the azure-storage-file-share like you pointed out
2. indentation - I have indentation issues where I thought it wouldn't matter in any coding language I had used so far but looks like Python does need to have proper indentation for it to work.